# Why does only "network" appear in Startup Disks on my Mac?

Tags: mac, boot-camp

I have a Linux dual boot setup with my Mac (with Leopard). When I open System Preferences > Startup Disk I only see "Network Startup" and no HDD or BOOTCAMP as expected.

So now, annoyingly, because "Network Startup" is the only option, it tries to start using the network (the flashing globe) for a short while rather than booting directly into Mac OS X.

Is there a way to either fix Startup Disk or manually hack this?

Comment: If you hold down the Option key at boot time, does it see your bootable partitions of your hard disk?

Comment: Yeah, I'm able to boot to the Linux partition just fine, but I have to wait a while for the annoying flashing globe to go away. Also, I'm able to use Flipside to restart automatically in Linux which is nice (and this skips the network flashy globe thing)... But whenever I want to use Mac OS, I need to wait for the globe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my [source](http://davespicks.com/writing/programming/mackeys.html#boot), by holding down `d` on startup (after the Mac sound), you can force the Mac to use the internal disk for bootup.

I hope this helps.

Comment: On Intel Macs, `D` during startup is used to [boot the Apple Hardware Test partition of Install DVD 1](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1533).

Comment: Holding down 'X' at startup should cause the Mac to boot from the first Mac OS X partition it finds.